# Parallel resistors with polarised capacitor

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, filter, design

I have been trying to choose the input capacitors for an SMPS and have noticed resistors being used in parallel with the polarized capacitors.

Since these designs are for an 800 V system, I am assuming the resistors are there to keep the voltage level across the capacitors divided and help in filtering the high frequency noises.

If I am right, is there anything specific I need to take care of before using the filter in my SMPS?

[image]

Comment: Hello ... do you know why there are 6 x 330 K resistors in series instead of 1x 200 K?

Comment: I am not sure, the BOM only describes them as standard thick film resistors from Vishay, so no extra information is provided.

Comment: @jonathanjo  I read the value as 3.3 kohm and this is an 800 V bus, so the resistor chain must dissipate 16 W, 1.35 W each. This solution may be cheaper or the the heat can better be dissipated.

Comment: @Jens That's 33k. Check the capacitors to the right for how a "3.3" looks like - there's a huge gap between the digits.

Comment: @asdfex Ah, yes, 33 kohm sounds better anyway. So it is 1.6 W total and this could be 75 V rated SMD resistors and 6 are used for creepage distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I am right, is there anything specific I need to take care of before using the filter in my SMPS?

You are correct in that they are used to balance the voltage on the capacitors. This is important for keeping the voltage on each capacitor within its specs, even when they may differ in leakage current.

Additionally they are used as [bleeder resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeder_resistor) for the capacitors. They drain the charge when power is disconnected, to avoid giving shocks to anyone opening the enclosure.

In the design, you should take into account:

- Dissipated power and the power rating of the resistors.
- Voltage rating of the resistors.
- Leakage current tolerance of the capacitors, the resistors must bleed enough current to keep the capacitors balanced.
- Time it takes to bleed off the voltage on disconnect (should be faster than the time it takes to open the enclosure).
- Creepage and clearance distances required vs. the contact spacing of the resistors.

I would aim for a 2x safety margin on all of these, as it doesn't affect the cost much.

Using a TVS or varistor in parallel with each capacitor can provide extra protection against voltage spikes and end-of-life changes in leakage current. Otherwise you may end up with higher than expected leakage in one capacitor causing overvoltage arc fault in the other capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

They are there to bleed of the high voltage on the capacitors when the circuit is shut down as a safety precaution.